# How to skip the split functionality for same value of split pattern in fn:tokenize

Tags: xquery, marklogic, stringtokenizer

I am trying to split a string (a delimited string separated using '|' or ','). I used fn:tokenize to implement this. Consider below the example text in which I have 4 columns text out of which in 3rd column i got the same value as split pattern.

`fn:tokenize("column1|column2|||column4", "|")`

Result of the above code is giving me 5 values in which 2 are empty:

```
column1
column2


column4
```

I also tried with adding quotes to column3 value, which is also not giving me the expected result.

Comment: To me the above looks like a delimited string for 5 columns, since you have 4 pipe symbols. Isn't that right?

Comment: No, It is a 4 column string. In 3rd column I got pipe symbol as a value. At this 3rd column I am facing the issue.

Comment: Ok, clear. Yeah, tokenize will not be sufficient. You'll need a recursive solution that chews off bits, and anticipates presence of pipe symbol in quoted values..

Comment: You need to specify the problem more precisely. For example is `|||||` one column containing `|||`, or two columns containing `|`? It seems to me this is a poorly designed data syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In MarkLogic 9 you can define your own custom tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `fn:tokenize` splitting by regular expressions and thus requiring `|` to be escaped, this seems like a horrible data format. Putting apart issues indicated by Michael Kay and expecting that `||` will always indicate a new field starting with `|`, and there are never empty columns, you can apply a simple hack and replace the pipe symbols by another character, and converting back afterwards. This requires you find some character in the Unicode range not allowed in your data set, though.

```
for $token in fn:tokenize(fn:replace("column1|||||column4", "\|\|", "|_"), "\|")
return fn:replace($token, "_", "|")
```

Result:

```
column1
|
|
column4
```

If the assumptions I made do not apply to your use case, you will have to determine another set of similar strict assumptions to be able to parse your contents.